# PHP cURL - PARSE server response

Tags: php, xml, curl, formatting

I'm not a programmer, and i need your help please.

I have a cURL function that returns a server response - either **success** or **error**:

***400 - Error Response:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><statusCode>400</statusCode>
<errorMessage>In order to be contacted, please enter a valid phone number.</errorMessage>
```

***200 - Success Response:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<statusCode>200</statusCode>
```

I need to validate response based on 200 or 400 StatusCode.

If status is 200, proceed as normal.

If status is 400 (error) then I need to eztract the error messag (strip out all tags) and ECHO error message only (in the example above - *In order to be contacted, please enter a valid phone number.*)

How do I do it? Please help.

Thank you.

CURL Code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: could you show us your php code?

Comment: and `$result` is string even when status is 400 ?

Comment: `$results` is just a raw server response - I need to parse this raw data

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am still not sure what exactly you are looking for
but you can try:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if($httpCode == 400) {
  /* Handle 400 here. */
  echo "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
}


$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($result , 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($result , $header_size);
 var_dump($header);
 var_dump($body);

curl_close($ch);
```

you are very welcome if any questions

Comment: If server response is 400 (error), that means user submitted wrong info. In that case I need to extract error message, and ECHO this error message to user. So I 1st need to identify if I got 200 or 400 status code. 2nd, if i got 400, then I need to ECHO just the error message

Comment: so? did you try my changes? did you get $header?

Comment: Here is what I get if I use your code and do `echo $result` - **string(207) "HTTP/1.0 200 OK Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Date: Wed, 14 Jan 2015 00:07:32 GMT Connection: Keep-Alive Content-Length: 139 " string(139) "2517111200" HTTP/1.0 200 OK Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Date: Wed, 14 Jan 2015 00:07:32 GMT Connection: Keep-Alive Content-Length: 139 2517111200**

Comment: check my updates, and now you can see the difference between curl response and 'server row response'

Comment: here is waht I get for `echo $header` - _string(211) "HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request Server:_ and a bunch of other code. ... so it does not work because I get too much unnecessary code --- I need to clean up the response I get ...

Comment: check `$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if($httpCode == 400) {
  /* Handle 400 here. */
  echo "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
}`

Comment: I get same long response with bunch of data: **Error: string(211) "HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Date: Wed, 14 Jan 2015 00:20:29 GMT Connection: close Content-Length: 149 " string(149) "Duplicate Entry400" HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Date: Wed, 14 Jan 2015 00:20:29 GMT Connection: close Content-Length: 149**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68780/discussion-between-roofing-calculator-and-kim-alexander).